# Solr JWT Authentication Plugin Configuration

Tags: solr, jwt

I have Solr 8.1 installed, and I have this sample JWT

```
HEADER:ALGORITHM & TOKEN TYPE
{
  "alg": "HS256",
  "typ": "JWT"
}
```

PAYLOAD:DATA

```
{
  "sub": "1234567890",
  "name": "John Doe",
  "iat": 1516239022
}
```

The secret key is "your-256-bit-secret"

Which generates the encoded JWT of

eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ.SflKxwRJSMeKKF2QT4fwpMeJf36POk6yJV_adQssw5c

I am following the documentation for Solr 8.1 about how to configure AWT authentication

https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_1/jwt-authentication-plugin.html#editing-jwt-authentication-plugin-configuration

Which says that the security.json file will have the the following JSON object

```
{
  "authentication": {
    "class":"solr.JWTAuthPlugin"
  }
}
```

Which can have a lot more fields like jwk

Can someone show me an example of how the information for the JWT e.g

HEADER:ALGORITHM & TOKEN TYPE

```
{
  "alg": "HS256",
  "typ": "JWT"
}
```

PAYLOAD:DATA

```
{
  "sub": "1234567890",
  "name": "John Doe",
  "iat": 1516239022
}
```

can be put into this object, and what field it should use

```
{
  "authentication": {
    "class":"solr.JWTAuthPlugin"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

After 2 weeks I finally figured out the answer.
So I wrote an article about it on my LinkedIn profile

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/securing-solr-8x-using-jwt-authentication-plugin-tyrone-tse/